# Left outer join in Teradata cannot get the full result of left subquery

Tags: left-join, teradata

I want to join two sub-queries:

```
(Select col1,col2,col3,col4, sum(money1) as sum_money
from table1 group by col1,col2,col3,col4)-----this is subquery1,
```

return 135 rows

```
((Select col1,col2,col3,col4, sum(money2) as sum_money_new
from table2 group by col1,col2,col3,col4) -----this is subquery2,
```

return 79rows

then I left join these two sub-queries like the following, still get 79 rows.

```
select subquery1.col1,subquery1.co2,subquery1.col3,subquery1.col4,subquery1.sum_money,subquery2.sum_money_new
from subquery1
left join subquery2
  on subquery1.col1=subquery2.col1
 and subquery1.col2=subquery2.col2
 and subquery1.col3=subquery2.col3
 and subquery1.col4=subquery2.col4
```

if I change the join above to be right join, still 79 rows.  who can help me?
the version of Teradata is 16.20.53.27

Comment: Do you have any additional conditions in WHERE?

Comment: no any additional conditions in where clause

Comment: I made a mistaken. yes, there is additional conditions in Where clause. After I get rid of Where clause, the number of return records are correct. Thanks!